# Why does -O to gcc cause "stat" to resolve?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, glibc

Tried to do a search, but didn't find anything. Whenever I try to compile a shared object and the test binary that links to it I get this error:

```
[root@hypervisor test-files]# ./test
./test: symbol lookup error: ./test-files.so: undefined symbol: stat
[root@hypervisor test-files]#
```

After playing around with it I found that if I feed `-O` to gcc during the compile, stat() starts working as expected. I haven't been able to find any indication online as to why -O of all things *fixes* a problem with an undefined symbol (or does it just mask an error instead of fixing it?).

Comment: You shouldn't need to link in any special libraries to get `stat`. Is this a cross compilation environment, or otherwise special build environment?

Comment: -On , n=0 no optimizations,n=1 ...n=3 all optimizations, -O0 removes all optimizations that could give the code an alternative form of execution

Comment: No just a regular RHEL6 machine.

Comment: You are talking about the compilation of your `test-files.so` file, not the test binary, right?

Comment: They're both being built by the same Makefile in the same directory

Comment: Is the `test-files.so` being dynamically loaded (with `dlopen()`)?

Comment: @mf_ I tried `-O2` in case it was me turning off optimizations, but I get the same behavior. Any reference to `-O` when compiling seems to make stat work (the function outputs something different based on file status without re-compile).

Comment: @user315052 yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood, the optimization triggered removal of unreachable code, removing the need for the symbol altogether.

When you built the `test-files.so` shared object, you likely did not use the C compiler but invoked `ld` directly. Thus, any library dependencies that `test-files.so` had would not be present. Loading the file dynamically would make it attempt to resolve the symbols with those already available within your `test` binary, and it could not be found.

Compiling with the optimization removed the unreachable code that called `stat`, and so the symbol did not need to be resolved on the call to `dlopen()`.