# undefined stat symbol after compiling with -fPIC

Tags: c, linux, zeromq, fpic

I'm using an (static) external library (zmq.a) in our code, and during the compilation process of our program it says

> ../libzmq.a(src_libzmd when making a shared object; recompile with
> -fPIC

However if I compile the library itself with -fPIC, our code now compiles but I received an error on launch:
"undefined symbol stat"

Edit: I use the following commands in order to generate libzmq.a (on rdht 7 x86):

`autoreconf --install && mkdir build && cd build && ../configure && make CFLAGS='-fPIC' CXXFLAGS='-fPIC' && make install`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44294173/1971013) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to solve it.
The way I changed the `CFLAGS` etc. **overrided** the other flags, I needed to just add the '-fPIC' instead.
One of the overrided flags was '-O2' therefore it couldn't find the stat symbol (as can be seen from the suggested answer before).